# Measure of how oscillatory a function is

Tags: functions

In the image below I have the plots of two different functions (the exact functions are't completely relevant, but just in case anyone wants a little bit of visual context).

[image: Two example plots]

I will have many functions behaving more or less like these two examples, and I need an automated way to distinguish them. As one of my ideas, I was wondering if there is any sort of measure of how oscillatory a function is so I could distinguish these. My thought process is that the one on the left has an extended region over which the function is slightly decreasing, whereas in the one on the right the function is highly oscillatory in the same region. Of course there could be multiple ways to achieve this, I was just wondering what is out there.

I don't want to rely on something that counts local maxima/minima because there are some examples of functions similar to the one on the left that have some oscillatory behavior before and after the nearly constant region (this is somewhat visible here, although I have functions where this behavior is more pronounced.

Comment: Can you afford to compute norms, say, $\|f^{(k)}\|_2$ for $k=0,1,2$?

Comment: @CarlChristian is that just the integral of the square of the kth derivative of the function over the interval it is defined?

Comment: Fourier transform

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @DougM Can you elaborate? I had thought of that as well, and what I was thinking is that the highly oscillatory function will have a larger peak about some frequency. Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: @CarlChristian Yeah that might be a little much for me, but just in case could you possibly expand on using that?

Comment: yes, if there is a distinct frequency to the oscillations you will see a corresponding spike on that frequency in the Fourier Transform.

Comment: Low pass filter and compare the signal energy over the interval of interest before and after filtering.  If your low pass filter knocks out a significant amount of energy, you know the signal originally had that energy in frequency components higher than the cutoff frequency of your low pass filter.